# How to configure Spring Security with already existing WebApplicationInitializer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am doing a web site project with Spring/ Spring MVC I learned how to configure a spring with the java classes and annotations approach, which by far is better than the XML.

Now I want to use Spring Security with my application. However I could not understand how to configure it with already existing `WebApplicationInitializer` ?

[The Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#jc) is not so clear.

Here is my code and what I have so far:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{
//public class AppInitializer {


    private static final Class<?>[] CONFIG_CLASSES = new Class<?>[]{SiteConfigs.class, AdminConfigurations.class};

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(CONFIG_CLASSES);

        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(appContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", servlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }

}
```

If I add `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` to the classpath the container throws 
 exception.

```
HTTP Status 500 - No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

So how to config Spring Security so that `springSecurityFilterChain` get initialized

Answer (score 2):

The exception tells you that you don't have a `ContextLoaderListener` which, in your case, is true. You only have a `DispatcherServlet`. By default Spring Security will only lookup the filters from the root application context (the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`).

If you want to let it use a `DispatcherServlet`s context instead you have to tell it that. You can tell it which to use by overriding the `getDispatcherWebApplicationContextSuffix()` method.

You aren't limited to a single `WebApplicationInitializer` you can have multiple in general you want to have one for your application bootstrapping and another to add security. You can then leverage the Spring convenience classes to save a couple of lines of code. See the [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc) for a sample.